# Post dynamic form field data to spring rest controller using ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, spring

I am trying to submit dynamic form data to spring controller using ajax so that i could save list of object later to the database. Everything is set but i am not able to handle dynamic form data in the ajax part. The problem is how to create the javascript object for each row of table and post those objects as JSON data. 
All the code is like this:

**HTML**

```
 <html>  
  <head>  
       <title>Add Students</title>  
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  </head>
<body>  
       <div class="container">  
            <div class="form-group">  
                  <form id="student_detail" name="student_detail">

                        <table class="table table-bordered" id="student_dynamic_table">
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="text" name="name[]" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="age[]" id="age" placeholder="Enter Age" class="form-control age_list" /></td>
                                <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">+</button></td>
                            <tr>
                        </table>
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-info"  id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                  </form>
            </div>  
       </div>  
  </body> </html>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  var i=0;  
  $('#add').click(function(){  
       i++;  
       $('#student_dynamic_table').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"> <td><input type="text" name="name[]" id="name'+i+'"  placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="text" name="age[]" id="age'+i+'"  placeholder="Enter Age" class="form-control age_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">x</button></td><tr>');  
  });
  $(document).on('click','.btn_remove', function(){

  var button_id=$(this).attr("id");
  //id of the clicked button
  $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
  });
$('#submit').click(function(){            
      var url= "${pageContext.request.contextPath}";

       var  student = ({
            name : $('#name').val(),
            age : $('#age').val()
        });  

$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : url + '/submitDynamicForm',
        data:JSON.stringify(  student),
        dataType : 'json',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        success : function(response) 
        {
        }
   });  }); });
```

**Controller**

```
@Autowired
private StudentDao studentDao;

@RequestMapping(value = "/dynamic", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView geDynamicForm() {
    ModelAndView form = new ModelAndView("dynamicform");
    return form;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/submitDynamicForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void saveUser(@RequestBody List<Student> student) {

    studentDao.insertListOfStudent(student);
  } }
```

**Model**

```
@Entity
public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "age")
private int age;

// getters setters

 }
```

**Hibernate to insert list of students**

```
@Transactional
public void insertListOfStudent(List<Student> student) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    for(Student std : student) {
        session.save(std);
    }
```

**Thank You in advance**

Answer (score 0):

```
var totalRow=$('#student_dynamic_table tr').length; // last row count
 var data={}; //object
 for (i = 0; i < totalRow; i++) { 
    data[$("#row"+i).val()] = $("#age"+i).val();  // adding value to data object which will be in  key value format({"ram:"21","hari":"25"})
}

data: { "jsonData": JSON.stringify(data) },  //  on your ajax data submit


 so now in you controller you can get the data with .key() and .value()  but make sure you parse with JSON.parse before .
```